# Is there a way to get extension id in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to get extension id of my chrome extension in extension codes. I know that extension id is a fixed string after being published to web store. But before it is published, the id changes when loaded from local folder. If I can get the id in codes, it will make debugging and testing much easier.

Comment: chrome.runtime.id

  You can see that string also in chrome://extensions page

Comment: Also in CSS there's `__MSG_@@extension_id__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.id` works! Thanks to @Robbi,
More info about propertyId can be found over [Chrome Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#property-id)